Is there a platform or software for centralised CV / work profile management for job seekers?
I am on quite a number professional/work-related social media platforms, job sites, freelancer marketplaces etc. eg. LinkedIn, Geektastic, HackerRank, Upwork, Fiverr.
If I wish to update my profile or CV on one platform, I then have to update the rest of the platforms manually. Is there a software or platform that can allow me to do this just once eg. by updating my CV or profile on it, which will then trigger an update in all the other platforms/websites/apps?
